# How to, in smalltalk,append two arrays

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, visualworks

Had to change this up. I have two arrays and I want to essentially concatenate them into one array.

```
 completearray:= completearray, temparray."concatenate the new array to the existing one"
```

How do I get this working please? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code works in Squeak, so what is the problem?

```
anArray := #(1 2 3 4).
anotherArray := #(5 6 7).
anArray, anotherArray "Returns #(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)"
```

Comment: That does not work in VisualWorks which is where my code is in.

Comment: Oh, ok. You tagged the question Squeak.

Comment: That will work just fine in VisualWorks, or any other Smalltalk.

Answer (score 1):

if your code doesn't run, you probably don't have an Array object in "completearray", but instead have an object that doesn't respond to #, (i.e. nil doesn't respond to #,).

Answer (score 0):

you are adding a character ($,), but you have to add a string with #, (cancat).
try: yourString , ','

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, why it may not work in your version of VisualWorks, but you can try to do this:

`completearray addAll: temparray.`

Source, just in case:

```
addAll: collection
    ^ collection
        do: [ :element | self add: element];
        yourself
```